# How to tell tell the ./configure file where to take the dependencies from?

Tags: macos, makefile, dependencies, libav, yasm

I want to install Libav locally in a folder and for that I have to install yasm (I can disable the dependency but I don't want to just for the sake of the argument). The installation of the package is done in the terminal via "./configure" and "make" (when I run "./configure" I receive the message, that yasm is missing). How can I tell to "./configure" to take it's yasm dependencies from the path "./libs" (there is a folder with libraries in the parent folder). Should I modify the makefile (and if yes should I change only the LDflags? to what?) or add the " --extra-ldflags="-L./libs" " to the ./configure command? What would be the use of cflags here?

Comment: I can't quite tell exactly what you're doing but note it's a very bad idea to try to unpack two different packages into the same directory: you say that it should look in "./libs" which implies they're in the same directory.  Anyway, you should run `configure --help` and see what options are available to allow it to find alternative locations for libraries etc.  There may even be a specific option for locating `yasm`.  You should _not_ edit the makefile, except for in the case of last resort, since your changes will just get overwritten again the next time you run `configure`.

Answer (score 1):

To have autotools' `configure` use dependencies from a specific directory, the following may or may not work, as the `configure` script can be written differently:

- `--extra-ldflags` (there should be `--extra-cflags` too) is fine, if it's there;
- for library dependencies, you can add `CFLAGS="-I<path>" CXXFLAGS="<same>" LDFLAGS="-L<path>"` to `./configure`'s environment or to its command line arguments;
- cleaner approach: if you have [`pkg-config`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) configuration generated and installed for your dependencies, you can specify a `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` instead. In special cases of cross-compilation, one can use `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR`.
- for local host executables, append/prepend to `PATH`.

Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19663/how-to-change-the-compiler-settings-with-automake